# Keyboard doesnt work on Asus E200H

Tags: laptop

I am new to Ubuntu. I have completely installed and replaced my OS on this laptop. Everything runs smoothly except for my keyboard; for when I do click a key it automatically brings up the sleep/shutdown options. I have looked through many different options throughout other sites and still turned up nothing. Please help!

Comment: I faced the same issue for Asus E200H with latest version of Ubuntu. I think you may try to use another version of Linux, i.e. another release of Ubuntu.
For my case, I'm now using Linux Mint 18 instead of Ubuntu. The only problem is that the sound card device is not found (it means there is no sound for speaker). There is another problem, cannot use gcc, but it can be resolved by below link.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/942305/i-cant-install-gcc-in-my-ubuntu Then I'm now happily using my Asus E200H in linux ;P

Answer (score 0):

I might be breaking some rules here, but i don't have enough rep to comment, so i ll try to present this as an answer.

For starters, no matter which key you press you get the same response(sleep/shutdown) or some other keys don't work at all, or have other crazy reaction?

If not; it seems like a hardware problem. So if you had previously open your laptop the cable-tape connecting the keyboard with the motherboard might have been moved out of place, so try readjusting it.

If you haven't touched the inside of your Computer this might be a problem with the motherboard.

Lastly, something that i would do, just to check what happens

> xinput list

This will display a list with every device, and its id, connected to your laptop.
Find the id of your keyboard (just the integer) and then type

> xinput disable [Keyboard_id]

then enable it again

> xinput enable [Keyboard_id]

Do this by using the on-screen keyboard provided by Ubuntu.

I hope this helped you.

I'll try to snoop around and shape this to a more complete answer.

Cheers